# enable query monitor plugin for all user type - none admin

Tags: wordpress

Trying to find some WordPress Hooks for specific user type (None Admin user type -Custom user type came with theme) to develop some function;
I had enabled [Query Monitor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).

I can see Query Monitor for Admin(s) only.

My Question is how to enable Query Monitor for <s>specific</s> all user type.

I googled but can't seem to find some tips.

I am open to any alternative plugin.

Searching my question's subject I [reached this link](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is_admin&type=).

But looks complected; is there any filter or action to reach the goal?

This snippet looks promising: [Line 81](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor/blob/12642d4674c2825bf57ca2e5d724295951a7ffce/collectors/debug_bar.php)

```
function qm_debug_bar_being_activated() {
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return false;
    }
```

**Update:**

- Toolbar enabled for all site users... only Query Monitor menu not
  showing for NONE Administrators.
- Site is still staging so It will be ok to show for all users.

**Update 2:**
Its not necessary to be this plugin... any alternative plugin will do.

Comment: according to user role we can manage this. All user are admin?

Comment: I want to debug for non Admin user type... custom user type comes with theme

Comment: So can you clear me that which user type can see this toolbar and which user can not?

Comment: Now only WordPress Administrator (Super Admin) , rest can't see Query Monitor Bar

Comment: Does other users can see the toolbar without query monitor bar?

Comment: Please check my latest answer it is resolved now according to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Line 85: query-monitor/dispatchers/Html.php](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor/blob/12642d4674c2825bf57ca2e5d724295951a7ffce/dispatchers/Html.php#L85).

Remove below code from the file you will find total three place we need to remove this code.

```
    if ( ! $this->user_can_view() ) { 
        return;
    }
```

In the same file you will find below code which also required to removed from the file.

```
  if ( is_admin() ) {
        if ( ! did_action( 'admin_init' ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! ( did_action( 'wp' ) || did_action( 'login_init' ) || did_action( 'gp_head' ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code is in he function is_active().

Generally, this is not the preferred way to change the core file of plugins but there is no filter or action to achieve your requirement due to that only his way is the preferable way.

Comment: I am reading again your comments... I can see the toolbar for all users... but can't see Query Monitor Function   .. Sorry I misunderstood your question initially... I am trying to enable Query Monitor for all user types

Comment: in that case you need to change the plugin file. go to querymonitor dispatchers html.php  and remove this if condition on line no 85

Comment: Oh , Worked like charm... was doing wrong file...can you please update your answer.. Regards

Comment: Thank you @akshay, CHARM

Comment: My Apology...it is showing now the Menu for all, but still no data.. I had un tick as answer so only not mislead other users..will try to find answer and update your post.

Comment: In that same file, same condition is applied can you remove all those three and check.

Comment: sorry! tried but still no luck.. if you have time to advise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172295/discussion-between-akshay-shah-and-wpdev).

Answer (score 4):

By default, Query Monitor's output is only shown to Administrators on single-site installations, and Super Admins on Multisite installations.

In addition to this, you can set an authentication cookie which allows you to view Query Monitor output when you're not logged in, or when you're logged in as a user who cannot usually see Query Monitor's output. See the Settings panel for details.

[image: Settings panel > set authentication cookie]

now you access Query Monitor for all users.
to deactive that clear authentication cookie
[image: clear authentication cookie]

[read more](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor#authentication)

Answer (score 1):

To enable the query monitor for every type of users, you need to give the `view_query_monitor` capability.

The below code enable query monitor for all users even for non-loggedin one

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user->add_cap( 'view_query_monitor' );

} );
```